# How to evaluate different angularjs directives in html code

Tags: html, angularjs-directive

I'm hoping that this is an easy question.  I have an array of items in javascript that I would like to display differently based on a directive name that they carry.  For example:

Here's the javascript to create a small array of objects.

```
var stuff = [];
stuff[0] = {directive: 'plain-text', toDisplay: 'some text'};
stuff[1] = {directive: 'super-text', toDisplay: 'some other text'};
```

Now, I want to have my html loop through the items and use the given directive to display them. I've tried a few things, but nothing seems to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: One way could be to create a helper directive that would put together a html string and then $compile it. 
But it kind of seems wrong - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My current code has a bunch of ngShows in the html, which is only going to require that any additional directives need to be added to the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @Jakub Judas comment -- you'd do this with `$compile` in a directive.

In the example below, we `reduce` the array into a string consisting of the new directives. We then use `$compile` to compile that string and finally use `append` to add the compiled html to the DOM:

```js
var module = angular.module('myApp', [])
   .directive('myTest', function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
       
        var stuff = [];
 stuff[0] = {directive: 'plain-text', toDisplay: 'some text'};
        stuff[1] = {directive: 'super-text', toDisplay: 'some other text'};
        
        var template = stuff.reduce(function(str, thing) {
          return str + "<" + thing.directive + ">" + thing.toDisplay + "</" + thing.directive + ">";
        }, '');
        
        var compiled = $compile(template)($scope);
        $element.append(compiled);
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('plainText', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div class="plain-text"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
      transclude: true,
    }
  })
  .directive('superText', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div class="super-text"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
      transclude: true,
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <my-test></my-test>
</div>
```

Note I'm using `ng-transclude` to display the text, but you could easily modify this to accept the text as an attribute.

Also note that this is unsafe if the directive names or text are fed in by a user dynamically -- in which case you'd want to make sure to escape the content appropriately.